# "Unfortunately, appname has stopped running" after attempting to use ActionBar.addTab

Tags: android

I've been trying to add tabs to the action bar while going through a few Android tutorials, but every time I use addTab, something breaks. My code currently looks like this:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

//      actionBar.setSubtitle("mytest");
        actionBar.setTitle("Title Goes Here"); 

        // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Here are a couple tabs
        ActionBar.Tab PlayerTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment A");
        ActionBar.Tab StationsTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Fragment B");

        // for each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        actionBar.addTab(PlayerTab);
        actionBar.addTab(StationsTab);

        // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
//      ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
//          public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//              // show the given tab
//          }
//
//          public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//              // hide the given tab
//          }
//
//          public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//              // probably ignore this event
//          }
//      };
//
//      // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
//      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
//          actionBar.addTab(
//                  actionBar.newTab()
//                          .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
//                          .setTabListener(tabListener));
//      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // First run
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        // return true;

        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void openSearch() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Search button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void openSettings() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    // Finding selected option item
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
//              menuItem = item;
//              menuItem.setActionView(R.layout.progressbar);
//              menuItem.expandActionView();
//              TestTask task = new TestTask();
//              task.execute("test");
//              break;
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If I comment out the lines with

```
    actionBar.addTab(PlayerTab);
    actionBar.addTab(StationsTab);
```

the code works okay (shows a blank tabs bar), but once I add them in, my app crashes.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs for [`FragmentActivty`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html):

> If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you
>   should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of
>   this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and
>   higher.

`FragmentActivity`'s `getActionBar()` is for API 11+. If your `minSDKVersion` is 11+ you should use the `android.app.Activity` version of `Activity` and get a reference of the `ActionBar` like you are doing now. If you want to be able to use `Fragments` and the `ActionBar` use `ActionBarActivity` which is part of the v7 support library